# forcing checkbox selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to find see if we can make a checkbox selected if we chose an option from the dropdown menu. Here's a mock-up code of what I'm trying to modify.

```js
$('.stackoverflow').on('change', function() {
  $(this).parent().next().find('input:checkbox').attr("checked", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="checkboxes">
  <div class="checkbox_wrapper">
    <input type="checkbox" id="How" /> How</div>
  <div class="checkbox_wrapper">
    <input type="checkbox" id="Do" /> do</div>
  <div class="checkbox_wrapper">
    <input type="checkbox" id="I" /> I </div>
  <div class="checkbox_wrapper">
    <input type="checkbox" id="Force" /> force </div>
  <div class="checkbox_wrapper">
    <input type="checkbox" id="The" /> the</div>
  <div class="checkbox_wrapper">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" /> checkbox
    <select class="stackoverflow">
      <option value="to">to</option>
      <option value="be">be</option>
      <option value="selected">selected</option>
      <option value="when">when</option>
      <option value="we">we</option>
      <option value="select">select</option>
      <option value="an">an</option>
      <option value="option">option</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox_wrapper">
    <input type="checkbox" id="not this one" /> not this checkbox but the previous one</div>
```

I'm trying to have the checkbox "checkbox" be selected if I do select an option from the dropdown menu. Is there an easy way to do this? When searching stackoverflow, the closest thing that I found was to have the next one be selected and not the current one. Thank you very much for any help at all.

Comment: So onchange of the select, set the checkbox by id.

Comment: Get rid of `.next()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reference the correct checkbox correctly?

In your case, you have this:

```
$(this).parent().next().find('input:checkbox').attr("checked", true);
```

- `this` refers to the `select`
- `parent` refers to `<div class="checkbox_wrapper">`
- `next` would then refer to `<div class="checkbox_wrapper">`
- and finally `find('input:checkbox')` would find: `<input
  type="checkbox" id="not this one" />`

Since the checkbox you want is a child of the same parent element that the `select` is in, the `next()` method call is what's causing the problem.

So, you could write:

```
$(this).parent().find('input:checkbox').attr("checked", true);
```

But, there are many ways to access an element. If it has an `id`, that is the simplest and most efficient way. So you are better off writing:

```
$('#checkbox').prop("checked", true);
```

Also, use `.prop` instead of `.attr` as `.attr` fails when you manually uncheck the checkbox and then select an item from the drop down.

```js
$('.stackoverflow').on('change', function() {
  $('#checkbox').prop("checked", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="checkboxes">
  <div class="checkbox_wrapper">
    <input type="checkbox" id="How" /> How</div>
  <div class="checkbox_wrapper">
    <input type="checkbox" id="Do" /> do</div>
  <div class="checkbox_wrapper">
    <input type="checkbox" id="I" /> I </div>
  <div class="checkbox_wrapper">
    <input type="checkbox" id="Force" /> force </div>
  <div class="checkbox_wrapper">
    <input type="checkbox" id="The" /> the</div>
  <div class="checkbox_wrapper">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" /> checkbox
    <select class="stackoverflow">
      <option value="to">to</option>
      <option value="be">be</option>
      <option value="selected">selected</option>
      <option value="when">when</option>
      <option value="we">we</option>
      <option value="select">select</option>
      <option value="an">an</option>
      <option value="option">option</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox_wrapper">
    <input type="checkbox" id="not this one" /> not this checkbox but the previous one</div>
```

Comment: Wait I can actually do this? Ok I knew that I was noob, starting just recently but I thought there was a function like next() but for the current that I wasn't aware of. Thank you very much!

Comment: @MIchelGeorgesNajarian There are many ways to access an element. If it has an `id`, that is the simplest and most efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options to check the checkbox:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".stackoverflow").on("change", function() {
       //$("#checkbox").prop("checked", true);
       $(this).prev("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", true);
   })

})
```

Here is a fiddle of it working based on your example: https://jsfiddle.net/gz6mab4k/

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. Like everybody else's input, it's been a great to help me undesrtand and learn about this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Hurray, you are using the relative position of your dom elements to locate each other.  I assume that's because you're going to get rid of all the IDs and add this structure many times to your page.  So you have a small error in the javascript handler, as mentioned in a comment you break stuff by having `.next()`, which will force the handler to look for a checkbox in the div coming after the select's parent which is the one that contains checkbox id='not this one'.  So you want:

```
$('.stackoverflow').on('change', function() {
  $(this) // the select
    .parent() // its parent DIV
    .find('input:checkbox') // the only checkbox in the parent div
    .attr("checked", true);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. As said in a previous comment I'm still a noob. How described everything is really good since you helped me understand exactly what everything does. Since I found this code in another stackoverflow post, I didn''t understand it completely.